# How do I parse JSON data into a table view?

Tags: ios, swift

all Im a noob at swift lets just set the record,

Im trying to parse JSON data from an external php file and display the data in a tableview, the data is from a php file hosted elsewhere, its values are

```
{
    'id' : '1',
    'username' : 'test',
    'password' : 'test',
    'email' : 'test@test.com'
 }
```

My code is as follows

```
class ForuthTableViewController: UITableViewController {

@IBOutlet var userTable: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var refreshButton: UIBarButtonItem!


var values:NSArray = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    getUsers()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

@IBAction func refreshPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    getUsers()
}

func getUsers(){

    let url = NSURL(string: "http://xxx.xxxxxx.xx/get.php")

    let userdata = NSData(contentsOf: url! as URL)

    do {
        values = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: userdata as! Data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! NSArray

        print("Parse success")
    } catch {
        print("Parse error")
        return
    }
    print(values)


    //userTable.reloadData()

}

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return values.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return 0
}



override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("userCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

    let maindata = values[indexPath.row]
    cell.username.text = maindata["username"] as? String
    cell.password.text = maindata["password"] as? String
    cell.email.text = maindata["email"] as? String

    return cell

}
}
```

I followed a tutorial on youtube of creating a login / register app but it was from an old version of xcode and when I copy the code across theres errors everywhere so not sure where to start,

Tried looking for a simple JSON tutorial but there are so many different ways to approach JSON I'm not sure which is the right one.

Any ideas would be appreciated, or perhaps a simple fix.

Comment: JSON are just Arrays/Dictionaries/Strings/Numbers. The JSON you showed seems to be a NSDictionary at top level (not a NSArray) (except if you didn't show it completely, of course). For the error, you didn't import `SpecialCell` I guess... And in tableView(_tableView:numberOfRowInSection) you seems to it twice?

Comment: Look for a better tutorial. You are strongly discouraged form loading data from a server synchronously (`NSData(contentsOf...`) and assigning `mutableContainers` to an immutable array is pretty meaningless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. got an error "Errors thrown from here not handled" : Catch the error.

   ```
   do {
       values = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: userdata as! Data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! NSArray

       print("Parse success")
   } catch {
       print("Parse error")
       print("Error: \(error)")
   }
   ```
2. error "IndexPath not resolved" : 
   You are using method `numberOfRowsInSection` instead of `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.
   Also override both methods.

Edit 1:

`override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {` 
should be: 
`override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell`

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return values.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "userCell", for: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

    let maindata = values[indexPath.row]
    cell.username.text = maindata["username"] as? String
    cell.password.text = maindata["password"] as? String
    cell.email.text = maindata["email"] as? String

    return cell

}
```

Comment: Cheers, managed to print the values from my request into the console now just need to try and get it into the table

Comment: No I removed it, since I didn't understand why it was there or what its used for now I'm trying to figure out what the indexPath is

Comment: updated my code to reflect my new error "IndexPath not resolved", where would I get the indexPath from ?

Comment: Clean up your `numberOfRowsInSection` methods. The only one which is valid returns zero.

Comment: see updated code, it still going on about its indexpath

Comment: @MrJoshFisher Your code in the question is still wrong, `numberOfSections` should return 1 (you can even omit it), `numberOfRowsInSection` must return  `values.count`.

Comment: Tried it error1 "Method does not override any method from its superclass" so I tried removing the override keyword and get the error that it conflicts with another objective-c superclass

Comment: In Swift 3 it's `override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell` and `tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: String, for: IndexPath)`

Comment: Error "cannot convert value of type 'IndexPath.Type' to expect argument type 'IndexPath'" losing the will now, cheers for this

Comment: @MrJoshFisher `indexPath` with starting lowercase letter, `IndexPath` is the type in the method line. Your next error will be `cell.username.text` because `UITableViewCell` doesn't have a `username` label.